# javamailsender always throws 500 error (springboot api rest)

Tags: java, spring, rest, email

ive a spring boot api rest app and I want to implement an email service for registration confirmation using javamailsender.

However i always get 500 error when i try with postman:

[image]

**mailController:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MailController {


    private final EmailService emailService;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailController.class);

    public MailController(EmailService emailService) {
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }
    @PostMapping("/registration-email")
    public ResponseEntity<Email> sendEmail(@RequestBody Email email){
        try {
            emailService.sendEmail(email);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(email,  HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch( MailException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

**EmailModel:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="email")
public class Email {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String emailAddress;
    private String emailContact;
    private String emailMessage;

    public Email(String emailAddress, String emailContact, String emailMessage) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.emailContact = emailContact;
        this.emailMessage = emailMessage;
    } //getters and setters
```

**EmailService:**

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService{

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    public void EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    public void sendEmail(Email email) throws MailException {
        SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mail.setTo("boemiastore@gmail.com");
        mail.setFrom("boemiastore@gmail.com");
        mail.setSubject("Contacto: "+email.getEmailContact());
        mail.setText("Le confirmamos que el registro se ha realizado con éxito ");

        javaMailSender.send(mail);
    }
}
```

**application properties:**

```
spring.mail.host=
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps

#Mail server Username & Password
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=

spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.timeout=8000
```

Anyone have any idea what is happening? Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Please log de exception you get in the try catch block inside `sendMail` method.

Comment: i dont see exceptions in heroku logs

Comment: Well, that's because you don't log them, at least in the code you share here. So, please log the exceptions so we can help you. A 500 error is too general to be helpful.